# Add non-string values to TableView in JavaFX

Tags: database, javafx, tableview

I am using JAVAFX and connecting to a DB. The query output should be copied to a tableview which I created in a stage. I would like to know how to achieve this. Also, cant we add non-string datatypes to cells in TableView?

The scenario is to query a SQL DB and send the result to the tableview which I already created. The SQL output does have non-string datatype values. I want to place the ResultSet values into the Tableview in a stage.

Here is the part of program where I am unable to proceed further.

```
        Connection conn = null;    
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table1","root","r1234");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (conn!=null) {
        text.setText("Connnection Established");
        }
        Stage secondary = new Stage();
        secondary.setTitle("DB Query Output");
        TableView TB = new TableView();
        TableColumn c1 = new TableColumn("SEQ_ID");
        TableColumn c2 = new TableColumn("START");
        TB.getColumns().addAll(c1,c2);
        secondary.setScene(new Scene(root,500,300));
        root.getChildren().add(TB);
        secondary.show(); 

        Statement q=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;
        String query = "select SEQ_ID,START FROM TABLE1 ORDER BY SEQ_ID DESC LIMIT 10";
        try {
            q = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }            
        try {
            rs = q.executeQuery(query);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }            
          try {
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    int SEQ_ID = rs.getInt("SEQ_ID");
                    float START =rs.getFloat("START");
                    System.out.print(SEQ_ID + "  " + START );
                    System.out.println();

                }   } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestFX.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }            
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands, your question is (quite a long way) off-topic for this forum, which is intended to address *specific* programming issues, rather than general "how to" type questions. I recommend you spend a little time browsing the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn about the site, and then if possible edit your question to show what you have tried and where your specific problems are. Including a [MCVE] is always a good idea. (And yes, of course you can have non-string values in a `TableView`.)

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your suggestions. Henceforth, will make sure to follow the site rules.

Comment: You need to create a class to represent the data in each row. Then when you loop through the result set, on each iteration create an object of that class and add it to the table's `items` list. I also strongly recommend not using raw types for the `TableView` and `TableColumn`s, i.e you should have `TableView<MyClass> tb = new TableView<>();` and `TableColumn<MyClass, Integer> c1 = new TableColumn<>("SEQ_ID");` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to fix this. I am using service and task to update the tableview. I have a BorderPane which contains a tableview and a textField. While updating the tableview, I would like to update the text in the textField based on the values in table. Is there a way to achieve this? This is the part of code which updates the Tableview

Comment: ArrayList<SQLObject> arrList = new ArrayList<SQLObject>();                             
ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL); 
while(rs.next()){  
kps.setKr6(rs.getDouble("B");
 arrList.add(kps);
                        
                    }                    
                    Iterator itr = arrList.iterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()){
                         
                         prodSqlList.add((SQLObject)itr.next());
                    }
                    updateValue(prodSqlList);

Comment: Basically, I am looping an SQL query and storing the results in the Tableview. The sceario is to bind the textField with a column in TableView. Based on the value of the column, my textField should show different texts.

Comment: I was able to get through that by creating a new Service class and assigning a task to it to update the TextField based on DB column value.